# Apply Background color for specific <tr> in angular

Tags: angularjs

I have one angular table.

```html
<tr ng-repeat="data in userList">
  <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
  <td>{{data.name }}</td>
  <td>{{data.age}}</td>
  <td>{{data.dept}}</td>
  <td>{{data.appDate }}</td>
  <td>{{data.joinedDate}}</td>
</tr>
```

Here when `joinedDate>appDate` ,for that particular row I need to add background color with `dottedlines`.
I did this

```html
<tr ng-repeat="data in userList" ng-if="data.appDate>=delivery.joinedDate" ng-style="{'background-color': '#ffd6d6','border':'dashed 3px #9e0b0f'}">
  <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
  <td>{{data.name }}</td>
  <td>{{data.age}}</td>
  <td>{{data.dept}}</td>
  <td>{{data.appDate }}</td>
  <td>{{data.joinedDate}}</td>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="data in userList">
  <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
  <td>{{data.name }}</td>
  <td>{{data.age}}</td>
  <td>{{data.dept}}</td>
  <td>{{data.appDate }}</td>
  <td>{{data.joinedDate}}</td>
</tr>
```

But rows are displaying two times.What is the mistake?Any suggestion?

Comment: Why not just style the `<td>`'s?

Comment: I need to apply background color  for` <tr>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your 2nd tr tag like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in userList" ng-if="data.appDate>=delivery.joinedDate" ng-style="{'background-color': 'red'}">
    <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
    <td>{{data.name }}</td>
    <td>{{data.age}}</td>
    <td>{{data.dept}}</td>
    <td>{{data.appDate |}}</td>
    <td>{{data.joinedDate}}</td>                         
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="data in userList" ng-if="!(data.appDate>=delivery.joinedDate)">
    <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
    <td>{{data.name }}</td>
    <td>{{data.age}}</td>
    <td>{{data.dept}}</td>
    <td>{{data.appDate |}}</td>
    <td>{{data.joinedDate}}</td>                         
</tr>
```

Comment: I don't think it should work. Can you post working image here